# Are there any strictly chloroplast/mitochondrion-residing ribozymes?

Tags: rna

A simple question that had occurred to me. Considering the small doubt of transcribed genes in both organelles, I would doubt it, but are there any known ribozymes strictly found in either mitochondria or chloroplasts?

**UPDATE**: Actually, I just thought of rRNA acting as a peptidyl transferase in mitochondrial ribosomes... Any other ideas?

Comment: can't we consider ribosomes as colossal ribozymes ?

Answer (score 2):

You've already mentioned **rRNA**. An interesting review [(Tanner, 2006)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1574-6976.1999.tb00399.x/full), outlines some more:

- **Group I Introns** - self-splicing; "They are abundant in fungal and plant mitochondria..."
- **Group II Introns** - some have been shown to self-splice; "...they are found in fungal and plant mitochondria, in chloroplasts of plants ... and especially in the chloroplasts of the protist *Euglena gracilis*."
- **RNase P** - involved in tRNA processing, found in mitochondria

None of these are strictly found in mitochondria or chloroplasts. However, the paper goes on to describe **VS RNA ribozyme**:

> The mitochondria of certain strains of *Neurospora* contain the Varkud plasmid (a retroplasmid), which encodes a reverse transcriptase, and a small, unrelated, RNA (VS RNA). The VS RNA is transcribed from circular or multimeric VS plasmid DNA by a mitochondrial RNA polymerase, and the resulting transcripts are subsequently site-specifically cleaved and ligated to form circular, 881 nucleotides long, RNA monomers. These monomers are then reverse transcribed and made double stranded to form the mature VS plasmid.
>
> In vitro transcribed VS RNA precursors are cleaved and ligated by the RNA itself and this is presumed to occur in vivo as well. Of all the self-cleaving RNAs, the catalytic properties of VS RNA are the most poorly understood.

---

**References**

> Tanner NK. 2006. Ribozymes: the characteristics and properties of catalytic RNAs. FEMS Microbiol Rev. 23(3):257-275.